# script don't work whit html5 doctype

Tags: html, doctype

I do not understand why this script does not work with the `<! DOCTYPE html>` but only with

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- // W3C // DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional // EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

can you please help me?

the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-3354,#menu-item-3419").on("click", function() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("pause");
    });
    $("#menu-item-3367,#menu-item-123,#menu-item-304,#menu-item-1048,#menu-item-2788,#menu-item-1046,#menu-item-3753,#menu-item-1045,#menu-item-1044,#menu-item-3719,#menu-item-3754,#menu-item-3755,#menu-item-3751,#menu-item-41,#menu-item-3418,#menu-item-68,#menu-item-123,#menu-item-2788").on("click", function() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
    });
    $.backstretch("http://www.keepradio.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/s.jpeg");
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://178.32.137.180:8713/;stream/1"
            }).jPlayer("play");

        },
        swfPath: "http://www.keepradio.it/wp-content/themes/soundwave/swf/",
        supplied: "mp3",
        volume: 1
    });
    $(".radio-wz-open-hidden").click(function() {
        $("#radio-wz #radio-wz-col").slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 100);
        $(this).toggleClass("clientsClose");
    });
    $("#radio-wz-col").show();

    function mouseHandler(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("radio-wz-hidden-open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
        } else {
            $(".radio-wz-hidden-open").removeClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
            $(this).addClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
        }
    }

    function start() {
        $(".radio-wz-open-hidden").bind("click", mouseHandler);
    }
    $(document).ready(start);

});
</script>
```

the part that should handle the "play" and "pause" of an audio player does not work with the HTML5 doctype. "pause"work but "play" don't work, and even  "pause" works only once

Comment: Can you please shows us the generated Javascript, not the PHP (from View/Source in the browser).  If you do that, then anyone who knows Javascript can help you.  As it is, you're requiring some PHP interpretation in order to help and the JS is not very clear.

Comment: I changed the question, I apologize but it is the first time that I make questions here and I do not know exactly how it works

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried it with any browser, chrome firefox, safari and opera  ... the only one that I have not tried is internet explorer